Applying change of variables to convert $2\ddot\theta(1-\cos\theta)+\dot\theta^2\sin\theta-\frac{g}{a}\sin\theta=0$ into an oscillator ODE
I want to try transforming
$$2\ddot\theta(1-\cos\theta)+\dot\theta^2\sin\theta-\frac{g}{a}\sin\theta=0$$
into an harmonic oscillator ODE via the substitution $u=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$. This ODE originates from solving the problem of a particle following a cycloidal path employing the Lagrangian formalism. If you do the substitution, you end up with (WLOG we assumed $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=+\sqrt{1-u^2})$
$$\small\left.\begin{align}
2\ddot\theta(1-\cos\theta)=-8\ddot u\sqrt{1-u^2}-\frac{8u\dot u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}&\\
\dot\theta^2\sin\theta=8u\dot u^2 &\\
-\frac{g}{a}\sin\theta=-\frac{2g}{a}u\sqrt{1-u^2}&
\end{align}\right\}
\implies -8\ddot u\sqrt{1-u^2}-\frac{8u\dot u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}+8u\dot u^2-\frac{2g}{a}u\sqrt{1-u^2}=0,$$
which isn't the usual $\ddot u+\omega_0^2 u=0$ type ODE.
Instead, if you part from the Lagrangian,
$$\mathscr L(t,\theta,\dot\theta)=ma^2\dot\theta^2(1-\cos\theta)-mga(1+\cos\theta)=8ma^2\dot u^2-2mgau^2=\mathscr L(t,u,\dot u),$$
and employ the E-L equation for $u$, it is direct and it yields
$$\ddot u+\frac{g}{4a}u=0$$
The question here is: are both methods correct? If they are, why is the first one not working? If only the second one works, why is that?

Both approaches are valid, but you have a calculation error:
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\theta}^2\sin\theta &\neq& 8u\dot{u}^2 \quad \mbox{but rather}\\
\dot{\theta}^2\sin\theta &=& \frac{8u\dot{u}^2}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \ .
\end{eqnarray}
With that correction, you should obtain the result you desire.

Both methods are correct, you've just made a simple error.
$$\theta=2 \arccos u \implies \dot \theta=-\frac{2\dot u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} $$
$$\ddot \theta =-\frac{2\ddot u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-\frac{2u\dot u^2}{(\sqrt{1-u^2})^3}$$
$$1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} \implies 2\ddot \theta (1-\cos\theta)=-8 \ddot u \sqrt{1-u^2}-\frac{8u\dot u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$
$$\dot \theta^2 \sin \theta=\frac{4\dot u^2}{1-u^2}2u\sqrt{1-u^2}=\frac{8u\dot u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$
As you can see, the first derivative term will vanish.
